# embedded hadoop-pig: what's the correct way to use the automatic addContainingJar for UDFs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

when you use pigServer.registerFunction, you're not supposed to explicitly call pigServer.registerJar, but rather have pig automatically detect the jar using jarManager.findContainingJar.

However, we have a complex UDF who's class is dependent on other classes from multiple jars. So we created a jar-with-dependencies with the maven-assembly. But this causes the entire jar to enter pigContext.skipJars (as it contains the pig.jar itself) and not being sent to the hadoop server :(

What's the correct approach here? Must we manually call registerJar for every jar we depend on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what's the certified way, but here's some pointers:

- when you use `pigServer.registerFunction` pig automatically detects the jar that contain the udfs and sends it to the jobTracker
- pig also automatically detects the jar that contains PigMapReduce class (`JarManager.createJar`), and extracts from it *only* the classes that start with `org/apache/pig`, `org/antlr/runtime`, etc. and sends them to the jobTracker as well
- so, if your UDF sits in the same jar as `PigMapReduce` your'e screwed, because it won't get sent
- our conclusion: *don't use jar-with-dependencies*

HTH