# my pig UDF runs in local mode but fails with "Deserialization error: could not instantiate" on my cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig UDF which runs perfectly in local mode, but fails with: could not instantiate 'com.bla.myFunc' with arguments 'null' when I try it on the cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my mistake was not digging hard enough in the *task logs*.
when you dig there thru the jobTracker UI, you could see that the root cause was:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
```

so, besides the usual:

```
    pigServer.registerFunction("myFunc", new FuncSpec("com.bla.myFunc"));
```

we should add:

```
    registerJar(pigServer, Maps.class);
```

and so on for any jar used by the UDF.

Another option is to use build-jar-with-dependencies, but then you have to put the pig.jar before yours in the classpath, or else you'll tackle this one: [embedded hadoop-pig: what's the correct way to use the automatic addContainingJar for UDFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636222/embedded-hadoop-pig-whats-the-correct-way-to-use-the-automatic-addcontainingja)